# The right place to set attributes in custom elements

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

Minimum reproduction - the js code part, line 5.

```js
class Bazooka extends HTMLElement {
  host;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.className = "hi"; // why ?? see bullet number - 5 --> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance
    this.host = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    let foo = document.querySelector(".test");
    this.host.appendChild(foo.content);
  }
}

customElements.define("bazooka-show", Bazooka);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <bazooka-show></bazooka-show>
    </main>
    <template class="test">
      <p>A shadow DOM.</p>
    </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

According to the html spec - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance bullet point - 5, `constructor()` shouldn't gain attributes right ?

> The element must not gain any attributes or children

My question is - why the custom element is accepting an attribute(className)? Shouldn't the browser throw an error ?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: @Rob edited, apologies.

Comment: (layman explanation) Attributes are DOM attributes. The Component has not created any DOM in the constructor yet (think using ``createElement``) so you can't set or read attributes in the constructor. Your ``className`` example is strictly speaking not an attribute, but a property (just like ``id``, ``title`` and those others _exposed_ as attribute.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman 
> Your `className` example is strictly speaking not an attribute
So what's a proper attribute then (which cant be set in the constructor) ?

Comment: Your own attributes, but if your testcode parses DOM **before** your ``constructor`` executes you won't experience an error. Mind you 9 out of 10 developers fall into this trap, thinking their code is fine.

Comment: for example, all online IDEs, CodePen, JSFiddle, first parse DOM, then execute script as if placed as ``<script>`` at the **end** of the document. Reverse that, put the script in the head, and many Web Components gurus post will fail. Related issue in the ``connectedCallback`` in [this blog](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-component-developers-do-not-connect-with-the-connectedcallback-yet-4jo7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually does throw when you call `document.createElement("bazooka-show")`:

```js
class Bazooka extends HTMLElement {
  host;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.className = "hi"; // why ?? see bullet number - 5 --> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance
    this.host = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    let foo = document.querySelector(".test");
    this.host.appendChild(foo.content);
  }
}

customElements.define("bazooka-show", Bazooka);
console.log(document.createElement("bazooka-show"))
```

Or if the element has already been registered when the parser meets it:

```html
<script>
class Bazooka extends HTMLElement {
  host;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.className = "hi"; // why ?? see bullet number - 5 --> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance
    this.host = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    let foo = document.querySelector(".test");
    this.host.appendChild(foo.content);
  }
}

customElements.define("bazooka-show", Bazooka);
</script>
<bazooka-show></bazooka-show>
<template class="test">
  <p>A shadow DOM.</p>
</template>
```

The thing here is that when the HTML parser meets your `<bazooka-show>` tag, your custom element has not been registered yet (because the script will be ran after).
So when it will [create the element](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-create-element), it will create an `HTMLUnknownElement`, which will get [upgraded](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#upgrades) when the custom element is [defined](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#element-definition) (step 19.).

When the constructor is [constructed](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#construct-a-callback-function) in [upgrade an element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#upgrades:concept-upgrade-an-element) (step 8.3) there is no check regarding the element's attributes. At this point it could even already have attributes, set by the parser.

On the other hand when we call `createElement()`, or `createElementNS()`, or when the element has already been registered when the parser meets it, we'll encounter the step 6.5 of [create an element](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-create-element):

> If *result*’s attribute list is not empty, then throw a "`NotSupportedError`" `DOMException`.